# Grand total not available in custom totals collector

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, totals, grand-total

I'm trying to add a certain fixed amount to the grand total of an order through a totals collector. But, for some reason, `grand_total` and `base_grand_total` are *always* `0`.

I've tried every `<before>` and `<after>` combination I could think of, but for some reason `grand_total` and `base_grand_total` are *always* `0`.

Am I overlooking something obvious here? Could anybody point me into the right direction? I'm using **Magento 1.9.0.1**.

Thanks in advance!

---

#### config.xml

```
<!-- ... -->
<sales>
    <quote>
        <totals>
            <discount>
                <class>ipsum/discount_quote</class>
                <after>grand_total</after>
            </discount>
        </totals>
    </quote>
</sales>
<!-- ... -->
```

#### Quote.php <sub>(all temporary, of course ;-))</sub>

```
<?php
/**
 *
 */
class Lorem_Ipsum_Model_Discount_Quote
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
    /**
     *
     */
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
        if ($address->getAddressType() != 'shipping') {
            return $this;
        }

        var_dump($address->getGrandTotal()); die();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
        if ($address->getAddressType() != 'shipping') {
            return $this;
        }

        $address->addTotal(array(
            'code'  => 'lorem_ipsum',
            'title' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
            'value' => 0,
        ));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is array **var_dump($address->getData());** return in collect

```
array (size=86)
  'address_id' => string '239' (length=3)
  'quote_id' => string '119' (length=3)
  'created_at' => string '2016-09-01 13:47:26' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2016-09-01 16:17:42' (length=19)
  'customer_id' => null
  'save_in_address_book' => string '0' (length=1)
  'customer_address_id' => null
  'address_type' => string 'billing' (length=7)
  'email' => null
  'prefix' => null
  'firstname' => null
  'middlename' => null
  'lastname' => null
  'suffix' => null
  'company' => null
  'street' => null
  'city' => null
  'region' => null
  'region_id' => null
  'postcode' => null
  'country_id' => null
  'telephone' => null
  'fax' => null
  'same_as_billing' => string '0' (length=1)
  'free_shipping' => string '0' (length=1)
  'collect_shipping_rates' => string '0' (length=1)
  'shipping_method' => null
  'shipping_description' => null
  'weight' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'subtotal' => int 0
  'base_subtotal' => int 0
  'subtotal_with_discount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'base_subtotal_with_discount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'tax_amount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'base_tax_amount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'shipping_amount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'base_shipping_amount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'shipping_tax_amount' => int 0
  'base_shipping_tax_amount' => int 0
  'discount_amount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'base_discount_amount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'grand_total' => int 0
  'base_grand_total' => int 0
  'customer_notes' => null
  'applied_taxes' => string 'a:0:{}' (length=6)
  'discount_description' => null
  'shipping_discount_amount' => null
  'base_shipping_discount_amount' => null
  'subtotal_incl_tax' => int 0
  'base_subtotal_total_incl_tax' => null
  'hidden_tax_amount' => null
  'base_hidden_tax_amount' => null
  'shipping_hidden_tax_amount' => null
  'base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt' => null
  'shipping_incl_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'base_shipping_incl_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'vat_id' => null
  'vat_is_valid' => null
  'vat_request_id' => null
  'vat_request_date' => null
  'vat_request_success' => null
  'gift_message_id' => null
  'extra_tax_amount' => int 0
  'base_extra_tax_amount' => int 0
  'recurring_initial_fee_amount' => int 0
  'base_recurring_initial_fee_amount' => int 0
  'cached_items_all' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'cached_items_nominal' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'cached_items_nonnominal' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'recurring_trial_payment_amount' => int 0
  'base_recurring_trial_payment_amount' => int 0
  'nominal_subtotal_amount' => int 0
  'base_nominal_subtotal_amount' => int 0
  'total_qty' => int 0
  'base_virtual_amount' => int 0
  'virtual_amount' => int 0
  'base_subtotal_incl_tax' => int 0
  'nominal_discount_amount' => int 0
  'base_nominal_discount_amount' => int 0
  'applied_rule_ids' => string '' (length=0)
  'nominal_weee_amount' => int 0
  'base_nominal_weee_amount' => int 0
  'nominal_tax_amount' => int 0
  'base_nominal_tax_amount' => int 0
  'msrp_amount' => int 0
  'base_msrp_amount' => int 0
```

code

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
    if ($address->getAddressType() != 'shipping') {
        return $this;
    }

    echo var_dump($address->getData());  die(); // it will show 00 the total is not set 

    return $this;
}
```

here is fetch result

```
    array (size=104)
  'address_id' => string '240' (length=3)
  'quote_id' => string '119' (length=3)
  'created_at' => string '2016-09-01 13:47:26' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2016-09-01 16:24:29' (length=19)
  'customer_id' => null
  'save_in_address_book' => string '0' (length=1)
  'customer_address_id' => null
  'address_type' => string 'shipping' (length=8)
  'email' => null
  'prefix' => null
  'firstname' => null
  'middlename' => null
  'lastname' => null
  'suffix' => null
  'company' => null
  'street' => null
  'city' => null
  'region' => null
  'region_id' => null
  'postcode' => null
  'country_id' => null
  'telephone' => null
  'fax' => null
  'same_as_billing' => string '1' (length=1)
  'free_shipping' => int 0
  'collect_shipping_rates' => boolean false
  'shipping_method' => null
  'shipping_description' => null
  'weight' => float 88
  'subtotal' => float 888
  'base_subtotal' => float 888
  'subtotal_with_discount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'base_subtotal_with_discount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'tax_amount' => int 0
  'base_tax_amount' => int 0
  'shipping_amount' => int 0
  'base_shipping_amount' => int 0
  'shipping_tax_amount' => int 0
  'base_shipping_tax_amount' => int 0
  'discount_amount' => int 0
  'base_discount_amount' => int 0
  'grand_total' => float 888
  'base_grand_total' => float 888
  'customer_notes' => null
  'applied_taxes' => string 'a:0:{}' (length=6)
  'discount_description' => string '' (length=0)
  'shipping_discount_amount' => int 0
  'base_shipping_discount_amount' => int 0
  'subtotal_incl_tax' => float 888
  'base_subtotal_total_incl_tax' => null
  'hidden_tax_amount' => int 0
  'base_hidden_tax_amount' => int 0
  'shipping_hidden_tax_amount' => int 0
  'base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt' => null
  'shipping_incl_tax' => int 0
  'base_shipping_incl_tax' => int 0
  'vat_id' => null
  'vat_is_valid' => null
  'vat_request_id' => null
  'vat_request_date' => null
  'vat_request_success' => null
  'gift_message_id' => null
  'extra_tax_amount' => int 0
  'base_extra_tax_amount' => int 0
  'recurring_initial_fee_amount' => int 0
  'base_recurring_initial_fee_amount' => int 0
  'cached_items_all' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item)[29]
          protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'sales_quote_item' (length=16)
          protected '_eventObject' => string 'item' (length=4)
          protected '_quote' => 
            object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote)[147]
              ...
          protected '_options' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected '_optionsByCode' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected '_notRepresentOptions' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected '_flagOptionsSaved' => boolean true
          protected '_errorInfos' => 
            object(Mage_Sales_Model_Status_List)[164]
              ...
          protected '_parentItem' => null
          protected '_children' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_messages' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_resourceName' => string 'sales/quote_item' (length=16)
          protected '_resource' => null
          protected '_resourceCollectionName' => string 'sales/quote_item_collection' (length=27)
          protected '_cacheTag' => boolean false
          protected '_dataSaveAllowed' => boolean true
          protected '_isObjectNew' => null
          protected '_data' => 
            array (size=69)
              ...
          protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean true
          protected '_origData' => 
            array (size=53)
              ...
          protected '_idFieldName' => string 'item_id' (length=7)
          protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
          protected '_oldFieldsMap' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_syncFieldsMap' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
  'cached_items_nominal' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'cached_items_nonnominal' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item)[29]
          protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'sales_quote_item' (length=16)
          protected '_eventObject' => string 'item' (length=4)
          protected '_quote' => 
            object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote)[147]
              ...
          protected '_options' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected '_optionsByCode' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected '_notRepresentOptions' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected '_flagOptionsSaved' => boolean true
          protected '_errorInfos' => 
            object(Mage_Sales_Model_Status_List)[164]
              ...
          protected '_parentItem' => null
          protected '_children' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_messages' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_resourceName' => string 'sales/quote_item' (length=16)
          protected '_resource' => null
          protected '_resourceCollectionName' => string 'sales/quote_item_collection' (length=27)
          protected '_cacheTag' => boolean false
          protected '_dataSaveAllowed' => boolean true
          protected '_isObjectNew' => null
          protected '_data' => 
            array (size=69)
              ...
          protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean true
          protected '_origData' => 
            array (size=53)
              ...
          protected '_idFieldName' => string 'item_id' (length=7)
          protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
          protected '_oldFieldsMap' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_syncFieldsMap' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
  'recurring_trial_payment_amount' => int 0
  'base_recurring_trial_payment_amount' => int 0
  'nominal_subtotal_amount' => int 0
  'base_nominal_subtotal_amount' => int 0
  'total_qty' => int 4
  'base_virtual_amount' => int 0
  'virtual_amount' => int 0
  'base_subtotal_incl_tax' => float 888
  'nominal_discount_amount' => int 0
  'base_nominal_discount_amount' => int 0
  'nominal_weee_amount' => int 0
  'base_nominal_weee_amount' => int 0
  'nominal_tax_amount' => int 0
  'base_nominal_tax_amount' => int 0
  'msrp_amount' => int 0
  'base_msrp_amount' => int 0
  'can_apply_msrp' => boolean false
  'servicecenters_amount' => int 0
  'base_servicecenters_amount' => int 0
  'freeshipping_amount' => int 0
  'base_freeshipping_amount' => int 0
  'rounding_deltas' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'weee_amount' => int 0
  'base_weee_amount' => int 0
  'applied_taxes_reset' => boolean true
  'free_method_weight' => float 88
  'item_qty' => int 4
  'tax_shipping_amount' => int 0
  'base_tax_shipping_amount' => int 0
  'shipping_taxable' => int 0
  'base_shipping_taxable' => int 0
  'is_shipping_incl_tax' => boolean false
  'cart_fixed_rules' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'applied_rule_ids' => string '' (length=0)
  'base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount' => int 0
```

here is result in fetch var_dump($address->getData());

```
/**
 *
 */
public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
    if ($address->getAddressType() != 'shipping') {
        return $this;
    }
 var_dump($address->getData());  die(); // here it will show 00 the total 
    $address->addTotal(array(
        'code' => 'lorem_ipsum',
        'title' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
        'value' => 0,
    ));

    return $this;
}
```